# Can Bubble Sort be categorized as a "decrease and conquer" algorithm?

Tags: bubble-sort

I have found many implementations of bubble sort online, referred to as divide and conquer solutions. However, I believe decrease and conquer is more appropriate, according to the definitions:

-A divide-and-conquer algorithm recursively breaks down a problem into two or more sub-problems of the same or related type, until these become simple enough to be solved directly.

-A “divide and conquer” should be used only when each problem may generate two or more subproblems. The name "decrease and conquer" has been proposed instead for the single-subproblem class.

Comment: Two subproblems of size `n-1` and `1` are still two or more subproblems. That meets the definition you have of divide-and-conquer.

Comment: It can be called whatever you want to call it. This is a matter of pure opinion.